# VASP DOS WARNING: charge density file is incomplete ERROR: charge density could not be read from file CHGCAR for ICHARG>10

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, density-of-states, charge-density

I'm working with a system of 192 atoms. I've already relaxed the structure (with `ISIF=2` and `ISMEAR=0`) and achieved the required accuracy. Then, as per the instructions in the VASP manual, I ran the SCF calculation. After that, I copied the obtained CHGCAR file to the DOS directory and attempted to run the calculation. However, every time I receive the following error message:

```
"WARNING: The chargedensity file is incomplete.
ERROR: The charge density could not be read from the CHGCAR file for ICHARG>10."
```

I have double-checked that the file is copied to the correct directory, and it is complete. Additionally, I have verified the dimensions (NGX, NGZ, NGXF, NGYF, and NGZF) in the CHGCAR file, and they are all accurate. Can you please assist me with this issue? The INCAR file is given below.

````
ISTART =  1                   
ISPIN  =  2          
ICHARG =  11         
LREAL  = A      
ENCUT  =  520  
PREC   =  Normal      
ISMEAR =  -5           
NELM   =  60           
NELMIN =  5            
EDIFF  =  1.0E-05       
LORBIT = 11             
NEDOS  = 1000           
NSW    =  0         
IBRION = -1         
POTIM = 0.5

LWAVE = F
```
````

Comment: Check with ISTART=0

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But it didn't work :(

Comment: Share your input file for test